# Breakpoint in service not working

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, service, breakpoints

I am trying to add a breakpoint to a service running on a separate thread. No matter where I place the breakpoint in the service, they are always ignored.

I am sure that the service is running as I see the `Log.e` in the logcat. My debug mode is also correctly used as any breakpoint in the main thread of the app works.

Am I missing something? Is debug mode not supported for services in a separate thread?

I just updated Eclipse and Android SDK tools to the latest versions today.

I am testing my application on a device.

Comment: Are you running the application in the emulator or on the device?

Comment: I am testing my code on a device

Comment: Look into this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-debug-service)

Comment: Is your service running in a different process? Have you set `android:process=":something"` in the manifest?

Comment: Thanks Abhay Kumar. The android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger() did the trick. Add your answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()` did the trick. Add this before the line of code you want to debug.

Comment: Warning - Do not leave this in production code. If you run your service and a debugger genuinely isn't attached, then any code after this line will not execute.

Comment: Wrap it in a `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG == true)`

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you declare the package name in the service tag in the manifest using android:process attribute, for example:

```
<service android:name=".YourCoolService"
            android:process="your.package.here"/>
```

Comment: lol, there will be the same process not different one than your app